# Purpose of Hermitian adjoints?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, complex-numbers, observables

During a QM lecture, we went over [Hermitian adjoints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_adjoint). While I understand that it is the Hermitian conjugate of an operator, I do not understand what this represents, besides its definition. Also, I do not understand the motivation behind taking the adjoint of an operator.

What exactly does an adjoint of an operator describe and how is the adjoint of an operator useful in quantum mechanics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the spectral theorem an adjoint operator has only real eingenvalues. Now, after you give a measure of your system, from the postulate of wave function collapse, you measure only the eingevalues of your operator. Since a measure is real number you need the adjoint property to ensure that the eingevalues are reals.

Obsviusly there are operators with reals eingevalues which are non hermitian, instead the requirment that your observables must be hermitian operators is a postulate of quantum mechanics.

Comment: You presumably mean "self-adjoint", no?